# Fire event after mouse has moved given number

Tags: javascript, events, count, pixel, mousemove

I try to change a welcome message based on mouse coords. It has to change after given a number.

There is somewhere a problem, but I cant figure it out!

```
var str = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut"],
    len = str.length,
    i = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    var count = i++,
        random = (count) % len;
    if (count > 60) {
        document.body.innerHTML = str[random];
        i = 0;
    }
    console.log(count);
};
```

A [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dWhrM/) for better interpretation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic will only ever generate the following calculation:

```
61 % len
```

Or at least it will only ever be output when `i > 60` and so your output will always be based on that calculation - not what you are expecting.

```
var str = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut"],
    last = '',
    len = str.length,
    i = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(event, r) {
    if (i++ > 60) {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * len;
        if ( last ) { str.push(last); }
        last = str.splice(r,1);
        i = 0;
        document.body.innerHTML = last;
    }
};
```

A version without reusing the previous value:

```
var str = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut"],
    last = '',
    i = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(event, r) {
    if (i++ > 60) {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length);
        if ( last ) { str.push(last); }
        last = str.splice(r,1);
        document.body.innerHTML = last;
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice! But, the approach with `Math.round` doesn't change the text exactly after 60...

Comment: @yckart Yes it will, it may change it to the same value previously however - which would make the change un-noticable.

Comment: Ah, damn I've not noticed that! Shame on me, thanks to you :)

Comment: @yckart no problem :) I'd recommend you changing your code slightly however -- what you are implementing will not work in some browsers because they do not support `document.body`. Plus you shouldn't really be using global variables like the above (although you may possibly have a scope wrapper that you haven't included in your question) ;)

Comment: @pebble don't worry about that! An anonymous function, and jquery will do the trick ;)

Comment: @yckart -- ah good good! :) you'd be surprised the number of people who aren't aware of using anon function wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut"],
    len = str.length,
    i = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    var count = i++,
        random;
    do {
        random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    } while (random == str.indexOf(document.body.innerHTML));
    if (count > 60) {
        document.body.innerHTML = str[random];
        i = 0;
    }
    console.log(count);
};
```

You were using some odd sort of divisibility calculation with the string length, just generate a random number between 0 and 2, save yourself a headache.

EDIT: Forgot the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dWhrM/6/)

Comment: @yckart It will in fact change after 60, you might be alluding to the fact it can change to the same value.

Comment: @Asad... heh my thoughts exactly.

Comment: @yckart I've changed the code to reflect your requirement. It ensures the change is to a different value.

Comment: @Asad Yeah, 've seen that... It is a bit bloating now, but ok, I've to accept ;)

Comment: @yckart reduced the bloat using do-while.

Answer (score 0):

i can see problem on the logic... you are changing inner html only when values go above 60 and you are resetting to 0 again that means it enters if condition only value is 61... and look at how are you calculating your random val .... since it goes to if condition when value is 61 and hence your random value will always be 1 when it enters the if condition and when it changes the inner text

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. The text should change on every 61st triggering of the mousemove event. Not a bug, a feature.

Comment: i know u already got the answer but at 61st triggering your random value is 1 and always picks the same value from array... now thats the bug i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this code...

var str = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut"], len = str.length, i = 0;
document.onmousemove = function (event) {
    var count = i++;
    if (count > 60) {
        var random = (event.screenX + event.screenY) % len;
        document.body.innerHTML = str[random];
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Random idea... however that would mean the same text would be shown each time you revisited the same pixel, not only that, if a user moved their mouse in a horizont or vertical line you'd get the same pattern of words -- obviously that could be desirable considering the question is a rather random request anyway :)